# AWS Redshift performance issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, amazon-redshift, flask-sqlalchemy, database-performance

I'm connecting to Redshift cluster using python+SQLAlchemy.

On AWS in Query History, Duration I see that query took near 0 ms, while if i measure it in code - it takes about 6/8 sec. I understand there is a network time involved, but still i don't think network delay is 8 sec when data amount is around 2K.

Any suggestion on what to check?

Comment: You can try in the Redshift Query Editor how long the query takes. Could be that your ORM consumes time in addition to the network transfer time.

Comment: @MP24 that what i did. In query editor duration is near to 0 but when i check in code it takes 8 sec.

Comment: Does the time spent when using your code include the setup of the DB connection or just the query?

Comment: @MP24 - just a query, (after the connection was already opened)